# Non-trivial examples of inner products induced by norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Every inner product induces  a norm and a norm induces an inner product iff it satisfies the parallelogram law.

Is there an inner product space that it is natural to define it as a normed space and the inner product is induced by the norm?

Comment: What do you mean by "natural"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That means there is a reasonable answer to the question “Why did you define it that way?”. If a definition of an inner product using a norm is much simpler and easier to come up with than the direct definition, it may be natural.

Comment: So the usual Euclidean norms on ${\bf R}^2$ and ${\bf R}^3$ are easier to come up with that the standard inner product on those spaces – does that count?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it does.